# How to run Finally() when all Observable async items are finished processing?

Tags: c#, linq, async-await, system.reactive

In order to have UI be more responsive I am outputting items in batches. The problem here is that `OnFinally()` is called before the last `OutputItems()` is finished.

```
    IObservable<IList<xx>> obs = Observable
     .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1), Scheduler.Default)
       .Zip(dirEnum.ToObservable(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
         .Buffer(100), (a, b) => b)
     .ObserveOn(syncContext).Finally(OnFinally);
    ...
    obs.Subscribe(async x => await OutputItems(x));
```

Is there a way to call OnFinally when all items are out?

Comment: I think this is the intended execution. `.Finally()` runs per batch as that is the continuation on each subscription. Perhaps you don't want to use `.Finally()` and instead you want to capture a collection of tasks and use `Task.WaitAll()` to await for all tasks to be complete.

Answer (score 1):

Project the buffers directly to your OutPutItems and do not use await inside Subscription

```
IObservable<IList<xx>> obs = Observable
     .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1), Scheduler.Default)
       .Zip(dirEnum.ToObservable(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
         .Buffer(100), (a, b) => b)
     .ObserveOn(syncContext).Finally(OnFinally)
     .SelectManay(X=>OutputItmes().ToObservable())
     .Finally(OnFinally);
    ...
    obs.Subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Subscribe` method does not accept async delegates, so your lambda is async void. Async void methods are not observable or awaitable, and their exceptions are not catchable (they are unhandled and crash the process). A solution is to project your batches to `Task`s of batches, and then back to batches with the `Merge` method. When you `Subscribe` you'll get the results of the tasks, in the order they were completed (likely not in their original order). If you are not interested to the results, just call `Subscribe` with no arguments.

```
IObservable<IList<xx>> obs = Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1), Scheduler.Default)
    .Zip(dirEnum.ToObservable(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
    .Buffer(100), (a, b) => b)
    .Select(x => OutputItemsAsync(x))
    .Merge()
    .ObserveOn(syncContext)
    .Finally(OnFinally);

obs.Subscribe();
```